# Htaccess redirection from domain.com to domain.com with parametrs

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem. This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+),([a-zA-Z0-9]+).html ref.php?id=$1&var=$2 [L]
```

I need a redirection:

```
http://domain.com/1,example.html > http://domain.com/ref.php?id=1&var=example
```

AND

```
http://domain.com/dir1/1,example.html > http://domain.com/dir1/ref.php?id=1&var=example
```

AND

```
http://domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3.../1,example.html > http://domain.com/dir1/dir2/dir3.../ref.php?id=1&var=example
```

I need universal solution for this problem.
I don't know where script is instaled, so I don't know tree of directories. I need Your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following rule should for you in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?:[^/]*/)*)([^,]*),([^.]*)\.html$ /$1ref.php?id=$2&var=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Well `ref.php` is your file, it needs to be present in every directory as per your requirements above.

Comment: This is working: RewriteRule ^((?:[^/]*/)*)([^,]*),([^.]*)\.html$ $1ref.php?id=$2&var=$3 [NC,L,QSA] :)

Comment: @fantom16: This is your first post on SO. You need to click on Green tick mark on the top-left side of my answer to accept it. You will also get some reps.